# Check Boxes in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert multiple Check Boxes (100+), but don't want to have to individually add them. Is there a quick way of doing this? I have tried the pull down method, and it does indeed make more, however they are all connected up - the same happens with copy and paste! When 1 is clicked they all are!

The macro that is fired when the tick box is clicked is as follows, I wonder if it can be altered?

```
Sub tick()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lColD As Long
Dim lColChk As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rngD As Range
lColD = 3 'number of columns to the right for date

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set chk = ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
lRow = chk.TopLeftCell.Row
lColChk = chk.TopLeftCell.Column
Set rngD = ws.Cells(lRow, lColChk + lColD)

Select Case chk.Value
   Case 1   'box is checked
      rngD.Value = Date
   Case Else   'box is not checked
      rngD.ClearContents
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: is it an option for you to use cells as checkboxes? let's say for example column A, C and E are checkboxes

Comment: Yes that is an option... How do I do that?

Comment: I tried your code with a tickbox and it worked fine - Application.Caller is referencing the correct tick box and placing the date on the same row in column D.  
Placing a tick in the box doesn't affect any other tick boxes either (using XL 2010)

Comment: Yes, it seams to be working for me now, not sure why I was having the problem!

Answer (score 2):

This is a code I use quite frequently. If you select a range and run this macro - it will add a checkbox for every selected cell and tie it to that cells value (boolean)

I don't use captions - but you can easily modify it if you would like.

I hope that this helps

```
Sub Add_checkboxes()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each the_cell In Selection
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(Range(the_cell.Address).Left, Range(the_cell.Address).top, 18, 12).Select
    With Selection
        .Caption = ""
        .Value = xlOff '
        .LinkedCell = the_cell.Address
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to the `Sheet-Module` in VBA and mark the columns you want to use as checkboxes with "Selection" (just an example). This procedure marks the specified cells with an "X" when double-clicked

```
Private Sub Worksheet_beforedoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    'If row 6 of a cell contains "Selection" all rows below are used as checkboxes.    
    If Me.Cells(6, Target.Column) = "Selection" And Target.Row > 6 Then

    'Function to mark the field with an "x"

          If Target.Value = "x" Then
              Target.Value = ""
          Else
              Target.Value = "x"
          End If

    End If
End Sub
```